# What happens to the string data when std::string objects are passed to functions?

Tags: c++

I've noticed something I don't understand happening to the string arguments to functions.

I've written this little test program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(string str) {
  cout << str << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string hello = "hello";
  foo(hello);
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
$ g++ -o string_test -g -O0 string_test.cpp
```

Under g++ 4.2.1 on Mac OSX 10.6, `str` inside `foo()` looks the same as it does as `hello` outside `foo()`:

```
12    foo(hello);
(gdb) p hello
$1 = {
  static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
  _M_dataplus = {
    <std::allocator<char>> = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider: 
    _M_p = 0x100100098 "hello"
  }
}
(gdb) s
foo (str=@0x7fff5fbfd350) at string_test.cpp:7
7     cout << str << endl;
(gdb) p str
$2 = (string &) @0x7fff5fbfd350: {
  static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
  _M_dataplus = {
    <std::allocator<char>> = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider: 
    _M_p = 0x100100098 "hello"
  }
}
```

Under g++ 4.3.3 on Ubuntu, however, it doesn't:

```
12            foo(hello);
(gdb) p hello
$1 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x603028 "hello"}}
(gdb) s
foo (str={static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x7fff5999e530 "(0`"}}) at string_test.cpp:7
7           cout << str << endl;
(gdb) p str
$2 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x7fff5999e530 "(0`"}}
(gdb) p str->_M_dataplus->_M_p
$3 = 0x7fff5999e530 "(0`"
```

So, what's happening to the value of the string when it is passed to this function? And why the difference between the two compilers?

Comment: Perhaps the stack is overwritten by some part of your code.

Comment: You need to find a section of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I just edited the question to give a reproducible example, divorced from my codebase. It appears to depend on the compiler.

Comment: Why do you assume you have a problem?  So long as the function prints "Hello" why does it matter what the myriad of internal data actually shows?

Comment: I wasn't actually saying I had a problem :) I'm just curious why there is a difference. What is one version of GCC doing that the other isn't? (It does actually work in both cases.)

Comment: Simply that between versions of GCC one or more of the parser, standard library code, code optimizer, and byte code emitter may have minor changes. It is a very active project, so changes are to be expected.

Comment: Look at the source for both implementations of `basic_string` and see.  Library implementers make a *lot* of specialized optimizations designed for the target compiler.  If I were to guess, there's a small string optimization going on, and that member doesn't do what you assume it does.  But who knows for sure?  The library.

Comment: @Dennis - yes, it looks like I'll have to go to the source. But SSO, which I just learned about thanks to your comment and @bdonlan's below, seems like a likely candidate.

Answer (score 2):

On my compiler `foo()` is inlined, so there is only one `hello`. Perhaps that is what is happening for you too.

What a program looks like in a debugger is not part of the language standard. Only the visible result, like actually printing "Hello", is.

Comment: It's also possible the copy undergoes small-string inline storage optimizations, and GDB isn't aware of the small-string storage

Comment: That sounds like it might be the answer. `foo()` isn't being inlined for me.