# what happens when pass std::string object by value?

Tags: c++, stl

we often passing string object by reference,but rarely by value.today,when gdbing a func call i was puzzled by passing string object with value.my code:

```
 fun1(string val,string& ref){
    printf("any thing....");
   }  
  fun2(){
      std:string val = "abc";
      std:string ref = "abc";
      fun2(val,ref);
    }
```

within gdb:

```
p ref
$1 = (string &) @0x7fff61f28a30: {
 static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
_M_dataplus = {
  <std::allocator<char>> = {
  <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
 members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>     >::_Alloc_hider: 
  _M_p = 0x1f230078 "abc"
 }
}
 p val
 $2 = {
 static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
 _M_dataplus = {
<std::allocator<char>> = {
  <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>      >::_Alloc_hider: 
  _M_p = 0x7fff61f28a40 "?
}
}
```

my question:

1. why "p val" does not print the correct content of variable "val" in func 2,does not the content be copyed to it?
2. even with "p val.c_str()" i can not print the content "abc" which is supposed to be in it.
   3.if passing string by value does not copy the original chars,does it mean we should never pass it in this way?

Comment: Do you mean `fun1(val,ref);`?

Comment: Try to completely disable optimizations, or actually use the variables in the called function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to the string data when std::string objects are passed to functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416808/what-happens-to-the-string-data-when-stdstring-objects-are-passed-to-functions)

Comment: Probably its related to COW implementation of std::string. Try to compile your code with `-std=c++11` and check this again, because C++11 prohibits COW for std::string. But I don't know for sure, it's just an option to check.

Comment: @ juanchopanza.YES,i mean fun1(val,ref).sorry for the typos

Comment: @Mat. what do you mean by "use the variables in the called function"?

Comment: @ Adam Burry.yes ,they are of the same question.but there is no satisfying answer.

Comment: Mat's comment about using the variables means, "use them so that the compiler won't optimize them away".  However, if it were optimized away, wouldn't gdb not be able to print it, i.e., say something like "variable 'val' not in scope?"

Comment: Thanks @Aaron that's exactly what I meant. As to how confused the debugger can get when faced with optimized code, there's really no telling. (I have no idea if this is the problem here, but it does feel like it.)

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the code, so try this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fun1(string val, string & ref)
{
    printf("any thing....\n");
    printf("%s\t%s", val.c_str(), ref.c_str());
}

void fun2()
{
    string val = "val";
    string ref = "ref";
    fun1(val, ref);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    fun2();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Do you understand what is happening in this code?
Does this require explanation?